# Multiplexer SN74HCS153 pulls the input selectors to high

Tags: microcontroller, multiplexer

[image]

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hcs153.pdf?ts=1709281704306&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F
I use the multiplexer SN74HCS153. Which multiplexes 4 inputs to 1 output. It has two channel but I only use one. A and B are the selectors (inputs) which select which input is put on the output.

Function Table:

[image]

When the GPIOs of the MCU are connected to the selectors A and B, my GPIOs who are connected to A and B are always pulled to high and I don't understand why. Shouldn't the multiplexer do nothing to the state of the selectors at all? Without the multiplexer the GPIOs work fine, as soon as I connect them to the selectors, they are pulled to high.

I tested it with a second multiplexer on a second PCB. Happens the same.

Does one of you have an idea why?
Basically connected to my mc like this but without channel 2 in use:

[image]

Comment: Pins 2 and 14 should be high-impedance inputs. With nothing connected to them, measure their resistance to VCC and GND. And what is the marking on the chips?

Comment: @CL. pin 2 and pin 14 are directly connected to the digital output GPIO pins of my microcontroller, like written, which should switch them to 0 or 1 depending on which input (pins 3, 4, 5, 6) should be multiplexed to the output (pin 7).  The problem is when my microcontroller puts the gpio to digital zero, it doesn't when connected to the multiplexer. They always stay "High"

Comment: Are your grounds connected together?

Comment: @RoyC Yes every ground is the same ground

Comment: Did you check that the GPIO pins of your MCU are actually set to output mode? If you disconnect them from the multiplexer, do the output levels change as expected?

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, that gpios do work as they should, when disconnected from the multiplexer. I can see it very good with a logic analyzer, that the gpios (which have been set to zero/low) are pulled high as soon as I connect to the multiplexer and pulled low again when disconnecting again.

Comment: Did you do the measurements I asked you for?

Comment: So you say that the inputs inject "high" with such a low impedance that the output pin is overwritten. I'd say the multiplexer is defect. Now you can verify/falsify this assumption.

Comment: @CL. I've done the measurements. They're around 0.660 MOhm

Comment: The input leakage current should be less than 1 µA, i.e., resistance > 5 MΩ, but I guess your multimeter has a finite input impedance. Anyway, to find out from/to where the current flows, insert small series resistors (bend up the pins from the PCB pads) and check the direction of the voltage drop. And what is the marking on the chips, and do they actually work as mux (with whatever channel is selected)?